# How to find 'influential points' in multivariate data with weak covariance

Tags: regression, pca, multivariate-analysis, cooks-distance, mahalanobis

Part-1: I have used PCA and Mahalanobis distance to find outliers. But in both cases, only the highest or lowest values are detected as outliers. I am looking for a way that any data point that does not follow a certain correlation between output and 3 inputs can be identified as an outlier.
I have multivariate data (3 independent, 1 dependent variable). I am trying to define the outliers based on not only their values being very high or low, but rather the points not 'behaving' similar to other data points.

Part 2 (Edit): I came across the concept of 'points with large residuals'. I searched for this term and figured that it should actually be called an 'influential point' rather than an outlier. So, I came across Cook's distance method, which seems to work at least for data fitted with linear functions. Now I am trying to figure out what can I do when the function describing the data is very complex. Any help in this direction is appreciated!

Comment: If "a certain correlation between output and 3 inputs can be identified as an outlier" means say $\hat y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_3$ then what you're looking for are points with large (+ or -) residuals $y - \hat y$; If that makes no sense to you or you mean something else, I think this needs a more precise story. The limiting case for this kind of question is "I am looking for a method to find outliers" and questions near that limiting case are too open to answer well. Also, many, many questions about outliers here, so have you looked at e.g. the most upvoted?

Comment: Thanks, @NickCox! I like the concept of 'points with large residuals. I searched for this term and figured that it should actually be called an 'influential point' rather than an outlier. So, I came across Cook's distance method, which seems to work at least for data fitted with linear functions. Now I am trying to figure out what can I do when the function describing the data is very complex. But thanks for the lead!